# WIn 2012/R2 How to find Powershell ISE 32 bit

Tags: powershell-v4.0

First, I don't see any matches for "ISE" when I click the start button and type "ISE".  I am able to run C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe and open ISE it seems to be the 64-bit, because I ran the following:

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

and it showed the response of "True".

How can I run the 32-bit version of Powershell ISE? Where is the .exe for it? 
It's V 4.0 of Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be located in: %systemroot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why it doesn't show up when I type Powershell or ISE from the Windows Start Menu.  I'm at a new client, and I'm used to seeing it show up there, but at this client is doesn't.